# what does test %eax, %eax with jns check?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have this assembly code here and I'm looking for an input that will make `test`/`jns` not jump.  I am unsure what test with jns is checking?

I see online saying it's checking the sign bit but the constraint before this step is to have edx to be 10 and eax to be greater than 10, which makes the most significant bit always to be 1 so idk how to proceed... if anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

```
  400f55:    0f af c2                 imul   %edx,%eax
  400f58:    85 c0                    test   %eax,%eax
  400f5a:    79 d8                    jns    400f34 <phase_2+0x24>
```

Comment: If you multiply `1` by `-1` the sign bit will be set. But if unsigned operands are large, the sign bit can also be set. If you take an 8-bit example: `4 * 40` is `160`, and bit 7 is set. The sign flag isn't set from whether a value is positve or negative, but from the the msb of the result. Signedness is in context.

Comment: If my number has the constraint that needs to be bigger than 100 how could this jsn not be met and not jump? since the first line says imul edx, eax and edx is 10 and eax needs to be > 10, next it says test(%eax,%eax) which eax now is greater than 100 so most sig bit is gonna be 1 all the time, how could this be done...

Comment: I don't really get the question, but in the 8-bit example, the sign bit will be set when the product is >= 128.

Comment: In your example, if you have 10 * 11, the product is 110. The sign bit will only be set if the (unsigned) product >= 2^63. The `jns` is testing bit 31 of `edx` (the product ms part).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Bit 31 of **`eax`** is tested, not `edx`.

Comment: so after multiplication of edx with eax, jns is testing bit 31 of edx, meaning I need to have the product of edx with eax to be >= 2^31? if edx is set to be 10 what input would this eax be?

Comment: @WeatherVane: It's a multi operand `imul` so not even the result is in `edx:eax`. Anyway the `test` instruction is clearly `test eax, eax` so the jump branches depending on `eax` bit 31.

Comment: Ah ok I missed the test part. But still, I don't get why OP thinks the msb is always 1.

Comment: I am just confused because after running the first line, eax in my layout regs it shows that it is now 110 ( if I put eax as 11 and since edx is set to be 10 so it turns out to be 110) and I can't get through the jump branch because of the result of test(%eax, %eax). and I am unsure what input eax should be then if edx is set to be 10.

Comment: if the most sig bit is dependent on this jump branch, and test(%eax, %eax) returns the same result, how could this ever be passed without jumping?

Comment: The most significant bit of *any* number <> 0 is 1. That what makes it the m.s bit. But the `jns` is testing bit 31, which isn't set from `110`.

Comment: Results between about 2 billion and 4 billion would have that bit set.

Comment: user18640236: You can say that bit #31 of the register is the MSB *of the register* and the fixed-width 32-bit integer it contains. It's also valid to talk about the MSB of the value as in your question and WV's comment, as the position of the highest non-zero bit (assuming unsigned), but that's unrelated to what SF is set from. (That's what you could find with `bsr %eax,%eax`). SF is set if the 32-bit value is negative, if interpreted as a 2's complement integer. (i.e. bit #31 is set, however it got that way, unsigned inputs or signed overflow). Give the multiply inputs that produce that.

Comment: I see I get how to have it not reach the jump branch now, thanks for the comments.